# OpenBLAS sgemm, special requirements? sometimes I get nan

Tags: c, blas, openblas

I have this declaration in my header somewhere:

```
typedef float real;
typedef int integer;
extern "C" {
extern int sgemm_(char *transa, char *transb,
  integer *m, integer *n, integer *k,
  const real *alpha,
  const real *a, integer *lda,
  const real *b, integer *ldb,
  const real *beta,
  real *c, integer *ldc);
}
```

Then I'm linking against the OpenBLAS lib (or optionally also other BLAS libs, e.g. MKL). And then I'm directly calling `sgemm_` in my C++ code. (The code should in principle work with any BLAS library.)

I'm not sure if this is a bad idea or not. Or what I should take care of. E.g. do I need a special alignment? Or do I need to take care in multi-threaded environments?

(E.g. I was looking a bit through the OpenBLAS code (`SGEMM` kernel specifically), and it looks like it assumes special alignment requirements (but maybe I got that wrong).)

It mostly seems to work fine. Except that in some cases (non-deterministically, maybe 10% of the cases, for some complex test cases, I get `nan` in my result; and it seems to not happen in our production code).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any problems calling BLAS from C++. OpenBLAS is a widely used library and it is not expected to have such a basic issue.

BLAS is basically a Fortran library, so you have to keep in mind that it uses Fortran storage format for two dimensional matrices. Meaning that matrices are single chunks of memory storing two dimensional matrices in column major order.

You cannot use two dimensional dynamically allocated arrays (i.e. `double **a;`) since the allocated memory will be fragmented. Also if you use two dimensional static arrays (i.e. `double a[5][4]`), you should keep in mind that in C/C++ the storage order is row major. In this case you could still use BLAS but you have to consider that the matrix is transposed.

I would suggest to use single pointer vectors (`double *a;`) and access the the matrix elements manually (`a[i+j*m]`).

OpenBLAS has multi-threaded support. On compilation you can define if it will use threads or OpenMP or nothing.

As far the error you get, I would suggest to check your memory, since such kind of behavior is usually based on memory bugs. In any case I wouldn't expect the error to be on the `sgemm` implementation, but in the way it is invoked.

Comment: As I wrote, it is already working most of the time. Thus of course I do not use two dim dyn allocated arrays (otherwise it would never work). Yes, maybe it is some bug in my memory allocation, but I already double checked, and I don't see anything wrong there. That's why I wondered, whether I maybe need to call some `blas_init` which I'm missing or so, or whether there could be other problems with `sgemm`.

Comment: Anyway, from the full reply you can keep that OpenBLAS (or MKL) is well maintained project and widely used library. It should work as it is from C/C++.